# Dockerized Mongo takes ages to load then doesn't run mongo

Tags: mongodb, docker

I tried creating a simple Dockerfile that installs MongoDB (using the standard docker tutorial) and then runs a python command:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
RUN echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu $(cat /etc/lsb-release | grep DISTRIB_CODENAME | cut -d= -f2)/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org python python-pip

RUN mkdir -p /data/db

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

EXPOSE 27017

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]

CMD python -c "print 'hello world'"
```

Then I ran `docker build .`

Unfortunately it was a complete failure.

1) Every time I run `docker build .` after making a change, it takes AGES to build and outputs insane amounts of logging, slowly re-downloading and slowly reinstalling every package - totally excruciating.

2) `docker ps` shows no Mongo running

3) The `python -c "print 'hello world'` command at the end says it runs but doesn't output the actual string.

Why is this so complicated?

My output: https://pastebin.com/igyYY8v1 (warning, long)

Answer (score 0):

Your Dockerfile is wrong.

Understand how CMD and ENTRYPOINT interact:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact

My particular advise is to use a container for the database and another for the Python App.

Answer (score 0):

The docker-way to do that is to split into 2 containers, 1 for the app, and 1 for mongo.

Try to think containers as *isolated processes* instead of small virtual machines. And think that there are a lot of software as docker images ready to run, like mongo and python as follows. **You will note that I did not apt-get installed nothing on my own.**

Try this with [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/):

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python

COPY ./requirements.txt /tmp/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app
COPY app.py /app

EXPOSE 27017

CMD python app.py
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
```

**app.py**

```
print("hello world")
print("bye")
```

To run it:

```
docker-compose up --build
```

Running with docker-compose as so, you can point to mongo from your python application as this: `mongo:27017`

---

PS: Regarding your timout, you need to understand how ENTRYPOINT and CMD works:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]

CMD python -c "print 'hello world'"
```

That tells docker to run this **single** command to start your container:

```
`/usr/bin/mongod python -c "print 'hello world'"`.
```

As you can see it makes no sense. ENTRYPOINT and CMD are kind of concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

When you change what is being done in your Dockerfile, depending on where those changes are, it can no longer use the previously cached layers for building. So if you change a `RUN` step, all later `RUN` steps will have to be redone when you rebuild.

Additionally, when an `ENTRYPOINT` and a `CMD` are used, the `CMD` string(s) will be appended to the `ENTRYPOINT`, generating the container's command string.

So basically, your configuration will be trying to execute something like:

`/usr/bin/mongod python -c "print 'hello world'`

rather than splitting it into separate commands.

You will really want to split this out into two different containers, one containing your python application and the other containing your database. Then you can compose a network for them to communicate over.